# Issues with cloth simulation-glitches and takes forever to load?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

I'm having trouble testing the way the shirt is going to lay down on my character,  it all works alright until parts of it glitch especially around the collar and stomach. This takes forever to load up, too...am I doing something wrong? Thanks!! [image]

Comment: After applying the modifier, there is 500,000 triangles. This is a lot and might explain why it takes long to complete the cloth simulation. I would think you might be able to reduce it to 30k.

Comment: I agree with @TTTTTTa, make a low poly version or copy. Once the shirt is finished you can add it to your high poly if needed